# How do I resolve Runtime Error -2147219712 (80040600):` The operation failed

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2016

The following code snippet works in Windows 10 / Outlook 2013.

In Windows 10 / Outlook 2016 I get an error at the `.send` line:

> Run-time error -2147219712 (80040600):` The operation failed.
>
> The messaging interfaces have returned an unknown error.  If the problem persists, restart Outlook.  Cannot resolve recipient.

```
Option Explicit
Sub email_test()
Dim objOutlookApp               As Outlook.Application
Dim objOriginalItem             As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objNewItem                  As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objInspector                As Outlook.Inspector
Dim objRecipient                As Outlook.Recipient
Dim strEmailAddress             As String
Dim strSubject                  As String

Set objOutlookApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
Set objInspector = objOutlookApp.ActiveInspector
'Set objOriginalItem so that it can be referenced
Set objOriginalItem = objInspector.CurrentItem
'Set objNewItem to create the new message.
Set objNewItem = objOutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
'Store the original body into the new item body
'Note:  objNewItemBody was altered by code not shown here
objNewItem.Body = objOriginalItem.Body
'Note: strEmailAddress was altered by code not shown here
strEmailAddress = "unique_ name@hotmail.com"
Set objRecipient = objOutlookApp.Session.CreateRecipient(strEmailAddress)
objRecipient.Resolve
MsgBox ("The objrecipient.resolved status is: " & objRecipient.Resolved)
'Set the fields of the MailItem.  Note:  objNewItem.Body was previously set
With objNewItem
    .Display
    .Subject = objOriginalItem.Subject
    .To = objRecipient
        'Loop through the attachments in objOriginalItem
        'Save them to the user's temp folder.
        'Attach them to objNewItem.
    .Send
End With

EXUNT:
Set objOutlookApp = Nothing
Set objOriginalItem = Nothing
Set objNewItem = Nothing
Set objInspector = Nothing

End Sub
```

In Outlook 2016 the `MsgBox` indicates "True",  The User Interface has a window open for the new mail object and the properly-formatted Email address is there.

When I click on the "To" field and then click "Send", the Email is sent.

Outlook 2013 yields a `MsgBox` indicating "False", but it sends the eMail with user intervention anyway.

How do I resolve this in Outlook 2016 to send the Email without user intervention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0x80040600` is `MAPI_E_CORRUPT_STORE`. In case of a PST store, that most likely means the PST file is corrupted - try to run scanpst.exe against it. In case of a cached Exchange store, try to delete the OST file and restart Outlook - it will rebuild the OST file.

MAPI error codes can be looked up in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author) - click "Error Code Lookup" on the OutlookSpy ribbon.

Comment: Hi Dmitry Streblechenko.  Thanks for looking at this.  I had no PST (No Personal Folders).  I have four eMail accounts on this Office 2016 device, and ran SCANPST on all four files a few times.  I ran the Outlook VBA again and got the same message.  I'm not sure if it matters, but the Outlook 2013 is 32 bit and the Outlook 2016 is 64 bit.

Comment: Hi Dmitry.  I thought everything was fine because SCANPST found a few problems with the OST files and fixed them.  I have 4 OST files and one of them indicated something like "Only minor discrepancies remain".  There was no option to "repair" that OST file when I ran SCANPST again.
Anyway, I renamed all the OST files and let Outlook recreate them.  The macro runs fine.  Thanks for the suggestion.
I assume that the "repair" feature of SCANPST isn't all that thorough.
Thanks again.

Comment: Scanpst.exe can be used against OST files, but only if rebuilding them is not an option (e.g. a very large mailbox and offline / slow connection). Recreating OST files is the preferred solution.

Answer (score 0):

`0x80040600` is `MAPI_E_CORRUPT_STORE`. In case of a PST store, that most likely means the PST file is corrupted - try to run scanpst.exe. In case of a cached Exchange store, try to delete the OST file and restart Outlook - it will rebuild the OST file.

MAPI error codes can be looked up in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author - click "Error Code Lookup" on the OutlookSpy ribbon).